# How can I show that this set has measure 0?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

## The Problem

Suppose I have the measurable set
$$E = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty\bigcap_{k = n}^\infty E_k$$
where $E_k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is measurable for all $k$. I want to prove that if $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty m(E_k) < \infty$ then $m(E) = 0$.

## What I tried

I think it can be shown that $$E = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty\bigcap_{k = n}^\infty E_k \subseteq \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty\bigcup_{k = n}^\infty E_k$$
Next let $B_N = \bigcup_{k = N}^\infty E_k$. Clearly since the sets may not be disjoint,
$$m(B_N) \leq \sum_{k = N}^\infty m(E_k)$$

and since $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty m(E_k) < \infty$ then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that
$$m(B_N) \leq \sum_{k = N}^\infty m(E_k) < \epsilon$$
Furthermore, it's not hard to see that $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty B_n \subseteq B_N$, so
$$m(E) \leq m\left(\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty\bigcup_{k = n}^\infty E_k\right) \leq m(B_N) < \epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon > 0$, then $m(E) = 0$.

Have I missed anything? If so, how can I correct it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: @Riemann But isn't $B(0,1) \subseteq B(0,2)$? I could be misinterpreting the definition of $B$ here, so can you please let me know what the definition is?

Comment: Oh, I see how to prove the inclusion. I think your proof is fine, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have another simple proof. We have $$\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}E_k\subset E_j$$ for every $j\ge n$, and from the convergence condition we have $m(E_j)\to 0$. Hence $$0\le m\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}E_k\right)\le m(E_j)\to 0,$$ forcing the measure to be $0$. Hence we have, by countable sub-additivity, $$0\le m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}E_k\right)\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}E_k\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0=0$$ and this completes the proof.